# How to access an ArrayList inside a map?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, arraylist, hashmap

So i have a data structure:

```
Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<Double>>> dataStructure = new HashMap<String, Map<String, ArrayList<Double>>>();

if(!dataStructure.containsKey(key)) {
                dataStruct2.put(key, new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>>());
        }
```

now how do I access the ArrayList it self, e.g. I want to put in a value in the ArrayList. Please explain what you are doing as well, I am quite a noob. Thank you, And I understand similar questions have been asked before, but I do not understand the solutions.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

To add a value to the ArrayList, simply do this:

```
try {
    Map m = dataStructure.get("<KEY>");
    for(String key : m.keySet()){
        dataStructure.get("<KEY>").get(key).add(<VALUE>);
    }
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println("null value found!");
}
```

This line of code gets the inner map and then the ArrayList itself so that you can edit it. If for some reason it runs into a null value, it will return an exception.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Works fine as long as both gets return non-null values.  Problems otherwise.

Comment: the problem is I don't know the value of the second key, it is basically text file i am reading and storing data

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
if(!dataStructure.containsKey(key)) {
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(2.0);

    Map<String, ArrayList<Double>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Double>>();
    map.put(someKey, list);

    dataStruct2.put(someOtherKey, map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
public void add(Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<Double>>> data, String key1, String key2, double addOn){
    /*
     * data - original data structure;
     * key1 - entry within primary data structure;
     * key2 - entry within secondary data structure;
     * addOn - value to be added to the list;
     */

    if(data.containsKey(key1) && data.get(key1).containsKey(key2)){
        data.get(key1).get(key2).add(addOn);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Error! Key1 || Key2 corrupt!");
    }
}
```